# QGIS 2.4 plugin PyQT qWebview javascript interface problem

Tags: javascript, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2.4, pyqt

I have a QGIS plugin which contains a `qtwebview` and Javascript communication between the page and the plugin.

It is working perfectly with QGIS 2.2  but not with 2.4  (both QGIS versions share the same plugin directory),

The javascript side never gets called with `evaluateJavaScript()` and the python side never gets invoked from Javascript either.

What could explain that it is working in 2.2 but not in 2.4?

```
def on_loadFinished(self):

...


def init_Clicked(self,iface):
    self.ui.webViewResult.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("QGISInterface", self.moTAZJsInterface)
    self.ui.webViewResult.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loadFinished)
    self.ui.webViewResult.load( QUrl(config["TAZ_URL_INTERFACE"]))
    self.ui.webViewResult.show();
```

Comment: Ok, I found a solution.  

Moving  the call to  addToJavaScriptWindowObject () within  on_loadfinished() solved the problem for 2.4 .

In 2.2, I was calling  addToJavaScriptWindowObject()  before loading the page ... following this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208166/how-to-put-result-of-javascript-function-into-python-variable-pyqt

Comment: Perhaps you can update your code and post it as an answer?

Comment: remember to reload/reinject your object if the QWebView page is reloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the answer.   I guess this can be cause by the introduction of multithreading in 2.4.

```
def on_loadFinished(self):

  self.ui.webViewResult.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("QGISInterface",  self.moTAZJsInterface)


def init_Clicked(self,iface):

  self.ui.webViewResult.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loadFinished)
  self.ui.webViewResult.load( QUrl(config["TAZ_URL_INTERFACE"]))
  self.ui.webViewResult.show();
```